# Keep reading from Angular JS HTTP call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

I am working on a web system, but fairly new to Angular JS.

The feature I am working on currently needs to do a POST call using Angular. That's not really difficult to do in Angular. But I want to keep reading from the socket.

The call I am doing takes a very long time (as intended) but I want the status of the call to be visible in my Angular app. So I'd like to send data back with the status, and this to be live visible in my app.

What's the best approach for this? I found the WebSocket demonstrations for Angular, but in that case I'd have to create my own HTTP implementation on top of WebSockets to be able to send POST requests.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP requests using the `$http` service take place in the background, so you can show anything you want while the request is actually being made. To get a sense of the status of the request it depends on how you'd like to measure that status.

Progress events on the `$http` object aren't slated to be added to Angular [until 1.6](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/11547), so if the delay is related to a large file upload you might need to create a service that wraps a raw `XMLHttpRequest` object instead of using `$http`. Here's an example
 from [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress):

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
oReq.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
oReq.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);

// progress on transfers from the server to the client (downloads)
function updateProgress (oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total;
    // ...
  } else {
    // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
  }
}
```

If the delay is serverside - waiting for a long running database query, for example, you might want to just fake a progress meter based on the average runtime of the query or show an indeterminate bar:

[image: indeterminate progress bar animated gif]

It sounds like you somehow have a way to monitor the progress on the serverside. In that case, you can make another request while the first one is in progress to get the progress information. You will probably need to send some state (like a query ID or request ID) to correlate the two requests.

Answer (score 0):

```
XHRCallToTheRestService()
   .then(function(result){
      //Hide status bar, data is back
    });

readMyStatus()
 .then(function(status){
     if(status == "finished"){
        //Do nothing
     } else{
        readMyStatus();
     }
  });
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interceptor. Whenever you do http call, this will intercept the call before send and after return from the server.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', function ($q, $location, localStorageService) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                // You can do some stuff here

                return config;
            },

            response: function (result) {
                return result;
            },

            responseError: function (rejection) {
                console.log('Failed with', rejection.status, 'status');


                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Or you can use https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui

Answer (score 0):

you could create a custom service using $HTTP to do a POST request like this:

```
site.factory('customService', ['$http', function($http){
     var httpProto = {
         success : function(response, status, headers, config) {
            return response;
         },
         error :  function(error, status, headers, config) {
            return error;
         }
      };

      thePostRequest: function(dataRequest){
         var output = $http.post(
               'http://74.125.224.72/',
                dataRequest
         );

         output.prototype = httpProto;
         return output;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For web sockets a friend pointed me to socket.io and I have used them successfully for Angular in several SPAs. Check [this material](http://slides.com/ryantucker/socket-io-and-angular-js#/) for more info.

G00d 1uck.